# C++ class for arrays with arbitrary indices

Tags: c++, arrays, indices

Do any of the popular C++ libraries have a class (or classes) that allow the developer to use arrays with arbitrary indices without sacrificing speed ?

To give this question more concrete form, I would like the possibility to write code similar to the below:

```
//An array with indices in [-5,6)
ArbitraryIndicesArray<int> a = ArbitraryIndicesArray<int>(-5,6);  
for(int index = -5;index < 6;++index)
{
    a[index] = index;
}
```

Comment: Any reason you cant use `std::vector` with an offset?

Comment: @David Rodríguez
By Unidirectional array, You mean regular C array?

Comment: @ezpz
Do You mean using a std::vector and writing v[indedx + offset] every time i need to access the element?
That is not good because:
a) You I will have to keep track of this because forgeting to offsett will cause an error.
b) I'm doing mathematical computations and the indices themselfs look like v[index + degree - gap]. Adding the offset of an array makes it even bigger of a mess and makes debugging this hard.

Comment: Sorry, I meant unidimensional (I wonder what I was thinking of). The question is whether you want to support more than one dimension.

Comment: @Bartłomiej: I was talking about using `std::vector` in a thin wrapper. The constructor would take the range and manage the offset transparently. The interface would be the same as your `v[index + degree - gap]`

Comment: Amazing to think this is has been a standard part of Ada since before it was released to the public in  1983 yet we're still here over 30 years later discussing how to work around the lack of such a feature in a supposedly more modern language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Really you should be using a vector with an offset. Or even an array with an offset. The extra addition or subtraction isn't going to make any difference to the speed of execution of the program.

If you want something with the exact same speed as a default C array, you can apply the offset to the array pointer:

```
int* a = new int[10];
a = a + 5;
a[-1] = 1;
```

However, it is not recommended. If you really want to do that you should create a wrapper class with inline functions that hides the horrible code. You maintain the speed of the C code but end up with the ability to add more error checking.

As mentioned in the comments, after altering the array pointer, you cannot then delete using that pointer. You must reset it to the actual start of the array. The alternative is you always keep the pointer to the start but work with another modified pointer.

```
//resetting the array by adding the offset (of -5)
delete [] (a - 5);
```

Comment: You've also created a memory leak.

Comment: Would there be a problem using -1? as array subscripts are really unsigned under the hood?

Comment: @David not really, you just reverse the operation performed to get the  offseted array when you want to delete the pointer.

Comment: @EvilTeach Microsoft say they are supported. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/59682zc4(VS.80).aspx

Comment: @yacoby yep. thanks nice link.   This is the only correct answer to the question.

Answer (score 4):

A `std::vector<int>` would do the trick here.
Random acess to a single element in a vector is only O(1).

If you really need the custom indices you can make your own small class based on a vector to apply an ofset.

Answer (score 2):

Use the map class from the STL:

```
std::map<int, int> a;
for( int index = -5; index < 6; ++index )
{ 
    a[index] = index; 
}
```

map is implemented internally as a sorted container, which uses a binary search to locate items.

Comment: The O(log n) lookup time is slower than the O(1) of arrays though

Comment: The alternative is std::tr1::unsorted_map that is the current standard implementation of a hash map, so it's most of the time O(1)

Comment: This wouldn't do the job. I need O(1) all the time.

Answer (score 1):

[This is an old thread but for reference sake...]

[Boost.MultiArray](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/multi_array/doc/) has an extents system for setting any index range.

The arrays in the [ObjexxFCL](http://objexx.com/ObjexxFCL.html) library have full support for arbitrary index ranges.

These are both multi-dimensional array libraries. For the OP 1D array needs the std::vector wrapper above should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Answer edited because I'm not very smart.

Wrap an `std::vector` and an offset into a class and provide an `operator[]`:

```
template <class T>
class ArbVector
{
    private:
        int _offset;
        std::vector<T> container;
    public:
        ArbVector(int offset) : _offset(offset) {}
        T& operator[](int n) { return container[n + _offset] }
};
```

Not sure if this compiles, but you get the idea.

Do NOT derive from `std::vector` though, see comments.

Comment: You should never derive from the STL container classes, since they all lack a virtual destructor.

Comment: No, no, no, never subclass an STL object. None of their methods are virtual and you will have problems down the road. Encapsulate the std::vector in your own class an passthru to the underlying vector most of the functions.

Comment: std::vector's d-tor isn't defined as virtual, so it's not a good idea to inherit from it.

Comment: I will admit, I wasn't aware of this... but what could go wrong in this specific case?

Comment: private inheritance would be OK though